# Changing background images of slice slider using wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following front-end markup which is for a vertical slider (slice slider) on my clients upcoming website:

```
<!-- Slice slider -->
<div class="slice-slider" data-slice-slider="arrows; loop; simple; vertical; slice-active; autoplay; autoplaySpeed:4000; arrows; arrowsLayer:1;slideEasing:swing; touchDrag:false; draggable:false;">
<div class="section section1">
        <div class="slide_caption_holder">
            <h1>Data Management & Governance</h1>
            <h4>Data management and data governance are intertwined</h4>
            <!-- <a href="#"><span class="cta_btn">Learn More >></span></a> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section section2">
        <div class="slide_caption_holder">
            <h1>Enterprise Data Strategy</h1>
            <h4>A competitive advantage to support enterprise goals</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section section3">
        <div class="slide_caption_holder">
            <h1>Regulatory Compliance</h1>
            <h4>Is often the initial reason for implementing data governance</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section section4">
        <div class="slide_caption_holder">
            <h1>DataOps</h1>
            <h4>Seeking to to break down silos across IT operations and software development teams and business</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Slice Slider -->
```

And my CSS:

```
.section {
    position:relative;
}

.section1 {
    background-image:url('../img/pexels-andrea-piacquadio-3760089.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#8DB3CA;
}

.section1::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    right: -10%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(44,89,110, .35), rgba(44, 89, 110, 1));

    -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform: skew(-15deg);

}

.section2 {
    background-image:url('../img/pexels-bill-emrich-230794.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}

.section2::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    right: -10%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(44,89,110, .35), rgba(44, 89, 110, 1));

    -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-15deg);
    transform: skew(-15deg);

}
```

Though Slice Slider uses src img as well, I chose this approach using divs with bg images.

my question is quite simply,  whats the easiest way for me to make the bg images editable (i.e I can change their paths from wp) ?

is there a way to turn this into a custom field ?  Or should I avoid using a custom css styles for my slider and instead, just place the imgs directly into the markup and target it that way ?

UPDATE:  Sure enough,  the problem was in the parent field named 'Vertical Slider' which was surplus to requirements.  I just created separate slide_holder fields of type group and inside these the following three sub fields:

a) Slide Image (slide_image)
b) Slide Title (slide_title)
c) Slide Caption (slide_caption)

return type of image set to URL.

and its working flawlessly :)

Answer (score 1):

Make them set the images from back-end through this:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

it's arguably the best custom field system there is. Extremely well documented, and very easy to set up.

After that then print the images as inline style instead of serving them via css:

```
<div class="section section2" style="background:url(/img/bg.jpg);background-size:cover;">
    <div class="slide_caption_holder">
        <h1>Enterprise Data Strategy</h1>
        <h4>A competitive advantage to support enterprise goals</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm already using ACF but not the pro edition.  This seems like a clever idea, I don't know why I didn't think of it myself.   Thanks a bazillion Marghen!